# "int() can't convert non-string with explicit base" but it is a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert some hex input into decimal RGB. Apologies if the code is bad, I'm new at python but I'm getting the error in the title even tho the input is a string? (I already printed the stuff to be converted into decimal before converting and they are all string)

```
v1 = input("Enter the first pixel value: ")
v2 = input("Enter the second pixel value: ")
#px_to_gen = input ("Enter the number of pixels to generate in between: ")

#group (r g b) values of v1 & v2 in a list
v1_ls = ["".join((v1[2],v1[3])),"".join((v1[4],v1[5])),"".join((v1[6],v1[7]))]
v2_ls = ["".join((v2[2],v2[3])),"".join((v2[4],v2[5])),"".join((v2[6],v2[7]))]

print(v1_ls)
print(v2_ls)

#convert values in v1_ls & v2_ls to decimal
i = 0
while (i <= 2):
    v1_ls[i] = int(v1_ls[i], 16)
    v2_ls[i] = int(v2_ls[i], 16)

print(v1_ls)
print(v2_ls)
```

Comment: `v1` is not defined in the code you have posted.

Comment: You've got it in a (never ending) while loop, eventually you're going to be making it try to convert an integer

Comment: @balderman yeah I fixed it now haha

Comment: @Sayse oh right! Thank you! So obvious now that I see it 

Comment: @StephanieHalim - No worries, i have no idea what you need to do to fix it, I presume you just need to add a `i += 1` after

Comment: Add `print` statements to debug your code. Demo: https://ideone.com/Pi4YdK

Comment: @Sayse Yup that tru (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're facing this error: `TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base`

This is because you're trying to convert a list directly to integer with base conversion.

To fix this you can try below code, (converting into string first).

```
v1_ls[i] = int(str(v1_ls[i]), 16)
v2_ls[i] = int(str(v2_ls[i]), 16)
```

But please remember that you need to fix a big issue with your while loop - it'll go in a infinite loop.

Comment: actually the list is all int so thats fine but someone had commented the infinite loop problem, thanks!